# rename files by removing the first 171 characters?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, zsh

I have thousands files downloaded from internet with naming convention like this:

`HTTP_services.cgi?FILENAME=%2Fdata%2FGPM_L3%2FGPM_3IMERGM.06%2F2020%2F3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20200301-S000000-E235959.03.V06B.HDF5&FORMAT=bmM0Lw&BBOX=-9,114.3,-8,115.8&LABEL=3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20200301-S000000-E235959.03.V06B.HDF5.SUB.nc4`

I want to rename all the file by removing the first 171 characters in the filename. So I will have a file with name "3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20200301-S000000-E235959.03.V06B.HDF5.SUB.nc4"

Is there any one-liner solution that I can use? I am using terminal in mac.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How to do that? Is it the code that I should enter in terminal?

Comment: I see. Because I have thousands file. So I will do a looping, and try to use this code ```for fl in *.nc4; do sed -E 's/.{171}//g' <<< $fl; done``` It's worked but only written in the terminal, not the file.

Comment: I have try it, but only written in terminal. ```for fl in *.nc4; do rename -n 's/.{171}//g' $fl; done``` and only with this ```rename -n 's/.{171}//g' *.nc4``` See attached pic https://share.getcloudapp.com/L1up6jdd

Comment: Thanks, after reading other threads, I should remove -n in order to actually changing the filename, -n is just for test and written in terminal. Its solved now. Could you please publish you solution as answer? So I can marked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the below regex:

```
.{171}
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`.`** - Represents a metacharacter representing anything except a new line.
- **`{171}`** - Represents a quantifier indicating any character can come 171 times.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/mgBVVw/5)

You can use the [GNU rename](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Renaming-Files.html) utility in order to execute the below command to achieve your result.

```
rename 's/.{171}//g' *.nc4
```

**Worth Reading:** [I can't run `rename` command on MACOS. What to do?](https://superuser.com/questions/152627/renaming-many-files-in-mac-os-x-batch-processing)

Answer (score 1):

rename is the best solution, but you can also use substring commands:

```
for file in `ls *IMERG*` ; do 
   mv $file ${file:171}
done
```

or alternatively using cut:

```
for file in `ls *IMERG*` ; do 
    mv $file `echo ${file} | cut -c 171-`
done
```

if you sure exactly 171 characters will work for each file name.

Comment: Yes it exactly 171 characters before the real filename, this is what you will get when downloading a subset of IMERG 30-min rainfall from GES DISC via wget. Anyway thank you for providing alternative solution, I tried it and worked too.